# Pass unbound object as CommandParameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a simple way to pass an object of type `Color` as `CommandParameter` in WPF?

I have a list of buttons which should change e.g. the background-color of my application.

The buttons would look like:

```
<Button Command={Binding SetBackgroundColor} CommandParameter={Color.Red} Background="Red" />
<Button Command={Binding SetBackgroundColor} CommandParameter={Color.Green} Background="Green" />
<Button Command={Binding SetBackgroundColor} CommandParameter={Color.White} Background="White" />
<Button Command={Binding SetBackgroundColor} CommandParameter={???} Background="#FF00FF" />
```

and on click on the colored button, the color should be changed.

Any ideas, patterns, best-practices, how-tos or workarounds for this?

Comment: `CommandParameter="{x:Static Colors.Red}"`?

Comment: Doh! True. That would work for the 'default' `static` colors. But, how about passing the color like `#FF00FF`? Any Chance to pass something like `CommandParameter="Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write

```
<Button CommandParameter="{x:Static Colors.Red}" ... />
```

or

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <Color>#FF00FF</Color>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

or use a color resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="myColor">#FF00FF</Color>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
...
<Button CommandParameter="{StaticResource myColor}" ... />
```